# How to show fetched data in input box as a dropdown and handle it?

Tags: reactjs

I am fetching country code API, storing it in select field as an option. I have one select field where user can select country and in another input box country calling code will display automatically. 
I am trying to select country value in input box and handleSelectCountry will select country and handleInputChange will target the country code and value will select automatically.

How I can achieve that?

```
componentDidMount() {
        fetch("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all")
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((result) => {
            console.log(result);
            console.warn(result);
            this.setState({ countries: result });
            console.log("i am in console");
          });
      }


   state ={
       name:'',
       countries: [],
   }
   handleSelectCountry= (event) =>{
    console.log(event.target.value);
    const myCountry = (event.target.value);
    this.setState = ({value: event.target.value});
    const selectedCountry = event.target.value;
   }
   handleInputChange = (event) =>{
       console.log(event.target.value);
       const myCountryCode = event.target.value;
       this.setState = ({value: event.target.value});
   }
    render (){
        return (
            <div>
              <div className="row col-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
              <div className="col-md-6 col-lg-6 ">
                <div className="input-group Form-main">
                  <select onChange={this.handleCountrySelectChange}>
                    {this.state.countries.map(country => (
                    <option key={country.name} value={country.name}>
                    {country.name}
                    </option>
            ))}
          </select>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>

<br />
             <div className="row col-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
              <div className="col-md-6 col-lg-6 ">
                <div className="input-group Form-main">
                  <input type="text" 
                   placeholder = " Auto Select" 
                   required="required" 
                   onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                   value={this.state.name}/>
               </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            {/* ----Form ends */}
       </div>
     );
    
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there are multiple things that seem to be going wrong with your code. I've tested the code and posted the corrected code below.

1. You're using this.setState wrong - the correct syntax is this.setState({name: event.target.value})
2. You're setting state to the value field in the onChangeHandlers but you're listening to this.state.name - so change that. In all the event handlers you need to have this.setState({name: e.target.value})
3. You have defined handleSelectCountry, but you are calling this.handleCountrySelectChange - this cannot work.
4. You're expecting the change in this.state.name to trigger the onChange event handler for the second input - that's not going to happen. What you can do is remove this.handleInputChange altogether. Add a variable to your state that says country code and change it in this.handleInputChange

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((result) => {
        this.setState({ countries: result });
      });
  }

  state = {
    name: "",
    countries: [],
    countryCode: ""
  };
  handleSelectCountry = (e) => {
    const country = this.state.countries.find(
      (country) => country.name === e.target.value
    );
    this.setState({ name: country.name, countryCode: country.callingCodes[0] });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="row col-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
          <div className="col-md-6 col-lg-6 ">
            <div className="input-group Form-main">
              <select onChange={this.handleSelectCountry}>
                {this.state.countries.map((country) => (
                  <option key={country.name} value={country.name}>
                    {country.name}
                  </option>
                ))}
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <br />
        <div className="row col-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
          <div className="col-md-6 col-lg-6 ">
            <div className="input-group Form-main">
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder=" Auto Select"
                required="required"
                value={this.state.countryCode}
                readOnly
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        {/* ----Form ends */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below: (I'm making use of hooks)

```
    const [state,setState] = useState({countryName:'',countryCode:''});
    const [countryMaster,setCountryMaster] = useState ([]);
    
    useEffect(()=> {
           //here you will have the fetch function
           //assume result have name, and code
            setCountryMaster(result);
           
          });
    
    const handleCountrySelectChange = e => {
    if(e.target.value!==null){
    var a =  countryMaster.filter(option => option.name===e.target.value);
    setState({
    ...state,
    countryName: e.target.value,
    countryCode: a[0].code
    })
    }
    
    }

//You will have to assign state.countryName to country dropdown
//You will have to assign state.countryCode to Input box
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. 1. The OP wants to display *country calling code*, not country code. 2. If they are already using a class, I wouldn't expect them to refactor it to use hooks.